# Why I can't use the isEmpty() method on vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was doing a pre-Lab assignment and in it he told us to implement many some methods like isEmpty(int[] arr). (I will include the question down below)
I tried importing many libraries but nothing worked and tried searching for a fix online but couldn't find anything about my my problem, and I am starting to doubt my self that maybe that we have to create the function and it's not build in, but he said in the question to implements so it's supposed to be build in.
Thank you for your help in advance.

**The error message:** The method isEmpty(int[]) is undefined for the type exercice1.

**The question:**

```
Write a java program that implements the following functions:
1. Method isEmpty(int [] arr) returns true if the array arr contains no elements otherwise false.
2. Method isFull(int [] arr) returns true if the array arr contains elements as the number of array length.
3. Method display(int [] arr) that displays the elements of the array arr.
4. Method InsertElement(int [] arr, int v, int i) add an element of value v to the array arr at position i.
Note: You must check first if the array is full or not before inserting the new element.
5. Method DeleteElement(int [] arr, int v) delete the element from array arr if it’s found otherwise return false.
Note: You must check first if the array is empty or not before the deletion.
6. Method OccurrenceNb(int [] arr, int v) returns the number of occurrence of certain number.
7. Method deleteAllEven(int [] arr) return the same array after deleting all the even numbers from the array.
8. Method EvenOrOdd(int [] arr) returns true if the number of even numbers is greater than the number of odd numbers otherwise false.
```

**My code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class exercice1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter an array to check if it's empty");
      System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: ");
      int n1 = input.nextInt();
      int arr1[] = new int[n1];
      readArray(arr1, n1);
      System.out.println(isEmpty(arr1));

   }

   public static int[] readArray(int[] arr, int n) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
         arr[i] = input1.nextInt();
      }
      return arr;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your job is to create methods on your own. This is the excercise.

Comment: @Zychoo yeah i think that what i have to do, to create the method and use but i wan to make sure that it's not built in.

Comment: No this is the goal of the exercice @Mohamedchokor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you are supposed to create your own isEmpty(int [] arr) method and then use it in your code.